# WPF Listview not displaying when I add an item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to add items dynamically to a listview in WPF, but I don't know why any items are displaying. Though it was a refresher problem, so I tried to use some ObservableCollection but it didn't work. 
I'm getting informations in two textblocs, and want them to show in the listview when I click on a button.

Could you help me understund the problem ?

My WPF with the listview

```
<ListView Name="listview" Margin="0 10 0 0" Height="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Recette}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding nomP}" Header="Nom" Width="250"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding quantP}" Header="Quantité" Width="100"/>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

My .cs :

```
public List<Produits> Recette { get; set; }
    public AjoutRecette()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAjoutProd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string nomP = combobProd.Text;
        int quantP = int.Parse(txtbQuantité.Text);
        Produits prod = new Produits(nomP, quantP);
        Recette.Add(prod);
    }
```

and here's what i've already tried with the ObersvableCollection :

```
public ObservableCollection<Produits> Recette { get; set; }
    public AjoutRecette()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAjoutProd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Recette = new ObservableCollection<Produits>();
        string nomP = combobProd.Text;
        int quantP = int.Parse(txtbQuantité.Text);
        Produits prod = new Produits(nomP, quantP);
        Recette.Add(prod);
    }
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Change `Recette` to `ObservableCollection<Produits>`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but it isn't working still, nothing is happening even using "public ObservableCollection<Produits> Recette { get; set; }"

Comment: As mentioned use the `ObservableCollection`. Also make sure `ListView` has the proper `DatContext`, otherwise the bindings won't resolve.

Comment: In your constructor add `DataContext = this;` after the `InitializeComponment()` clall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, please check the following points:

1. Please change `Recette` to be of type `ObservableCollection<Produits>` instead of `List<Produits>`. You would need to adjust the property type as well as the part of code where you instantiate the collection.
   You can simply do:

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<Produits> Recette { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Produits>();
   ```
2. Make sure that the `DataContext` property is set correctly. One way of doing that would be to set `DataContext` in the constructor of `AjoutRecette`:

   ```
   public AjoutRecette()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       listview.DataContext = this;
   }
   ```
3. Also, please make sure that properties `nomP` and `quantP` are present in the `Produits` class.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your clear answer ! I just tried again with this way of instantiate the collection but nothing more. I didn't really get the "grid.DataContext = this", where am I suppose to set that ? And nomP and quantP are present in the class.

Comment: Hi @Matthieu. Actually, we should be able to make it work without taking into account the parent element. Can you please try calling:
`listview.DataContext = this;` in the constructor of `AjoutRecette`?

Comment: You should avoid setting the `DataContext` explicitly on specific elements. Better set it on on the top level element e.g. `Window` or `UserControl` to make use of the `DataContet` inheritance. For this reason it should be `this.DataContext = this;` in the constructor. This way you also omit the need to have named controls for the sake of initialization only.

Comment: That's a good point @BionicCode. Going forward, Matthieu, please consider looking into the MVVM pattern and binding to ViewModel classes rather than to code behind. It would nicely decouple the view layer from the view model (stuff you bind to) and make the solution more maintainable in the future. Happy coding! :)